# Unable to pass props in Next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am making a Server Side Rendering application using Next Js (React SSR).

**Index.js** (Simply calling another component Layout in index)

```
import Layout from "./layout";
import React from "react";

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Layout />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

**Layout.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Product from "./product";

class Layout extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps() {
    const res = await fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/developit/preact");
    console.log(res);
    const json = await res.json();
    return { stars: json.stargazers_count };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("userLoggedIn")) {
      //Get products details for logged in user api
      //For now let us consider the same api
      // const res = fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/developit/preact");
      // const json = res.json(); // better use it inside try .. catch
      // return { stars: json.stargazers_count };
    } else {
      // Get product details for guest user api
      //For now let us consider the same api
      // const res = fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/developit/preact");
      // const json = res.json(); 
      // return { stars: json.stargazers_count };
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        This is layout page
        <Product stars={this.props.stars} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Layout;
```

**Complete simple application example is here**: **https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-getinitialprops-748d5**

My problem here is, I am trying to pass props to `product` page from `layout` page and props are received from `getInitialProps` (SSR).. But you could see in the example provided, the props didn't works and it still gives **undefined** for `this.props.stars` .

If I move this code into `componentDidMount` and using `setState` and passing state as props would work but that will not display the data fetched from api in view page source.

**Note:** Please don't move this logic into index.js file where it works but in my real application It is dynamic routing page and I will fetch api as per the query param fetched on that page.

If you get into this link https://748d5.sse.codesandbox.io/ and click `ctrl + u` then you would see the source where I am also need the dynamic content fetched from api.

To achieve this dynamic content(stars count here in this example) display in view source only I am doing all these which is meant for SEO purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, you can't call `getInitialProps` from a child component: [getInitialProps caveats](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps#caveats).

> getInitialProps **can not be used in children components**, only in the default export of every page

Your `Layout` page is a child component of `Home`.

If you want to call `getInitialProps`, then you'll either need to define `getInitialProps` from within the `Home` page OR create a wrapper component that calls its own `getInitialProps` that will wrap the page's `default export PageComponet` with this wrapper component: `export default withStarsData(PageComponent)`; as a result, this wrapper component will then pass `PageComponent` some `props`.

If you want to make this function flexible/dynamic, then use [ctx](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps#context-object)'s `query` parameter with a [dynamic route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes).

This is a rather complex solution to understand, but in brief, it allows the home (`/`) and layout (`/layout`) pages to fetch the same data. If you don't want to fetch the data multiple times, but instead, fetch ONCE and then share between pages, then you'll want to use a higher-order state provider like [redux](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux).

**Working example**:

[image: Edit GetInitialProps Wrapper]

---

**components/withStars/index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch";

// 1.) this function accepts a page Component and...
const withStars = WrappedComponent => {

  // 7.) if stars data is present, returns <WrappedComponent {...props} /> with props
  // else if there's an error, returns the error
  // else returns a "Loading..." indicator
  const FetchStarsData = props =>
    props.stars ? (
      <WrappedComponent {...props} />
    ) : props.error ? (
      <div>Fetch error: {props.error} </div>
    ) : (
      <div>Loading...</div>
    );

  // 3.) this first calls the above function's getInitialProps
  FetchStarsData.getInitialProps = async ctx => {

    // 4.) here's where we fetch "stars" data
    let stars;
    let error;
    try {
      const res = await fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/developit/preact");
      const json = await res.json();
      stars = json.stargazers_count;
    } catch (e) {
      error = e.toString();
    }

    // 5.) optionally this will call the <WrappedComponent/> 
    // getInitialProps if it has been defined
    if (WrappedComponent.getInitialProps)
      await WrappedComponent.getInitialProps(ctx);

    // 6.) this returns stars/error data to the FetchStarsData function above
    return { stars, error };
  };

  // 2.) ...returns the result of the "FetchStarsData" function
  return FetchStarsData;
};

export default withStars;
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. Really struggled for a long to get one good answer and thanks for this.. And appreciate your time and working example via sandbox.. I will implement in my real project and will get back to you if any queries..

Comment: your answer helped me a lot too! How do I make a map with data from json? 
Using the github repository API example, I need to get all the names and ids and print them on my index page and also on the profile

Comment: The major problem with your example code is that the `data` prop is initially undefined because it's asynchronously defined (meaning it takes time for the request to resolve and for `data` to be defined as `JSON`). Because of this, you can't `map` over an `undefined` variable. The solution is to [conditionally render](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) the `data`. In your case, you'll conditionally `map` over the `data` when `data && data.length > 0` (data is defined and has a length greater than 0).

Comment: humm, perfect! I will try! Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have any example?

Comment: Example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/getinitialprops-wrapper-fetching-json-kro43)