# Load component containing getStaticProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using NextJs in a project and and I created a component where I load dynamic data, if I load via `localhost:3000/faq`, it works normally, but if I try to import that same component into `index.js`, an error occurs. I probably need to pass props, but I don't know how to do that.

This is my faq.js

```
import React from 'react'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'


function Faq({ data }) {
    return (
    <div>
        <ul>
            {data.map((item) => (
            <li key={item.id}>{item.question}{item.answer}</li>
            ))}
        </ul>        
    </div>

    )
  }

  export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await fetch('./data/faq.json')
    const data = await res.json()

    return {
      props: {
        data,
      },
    }
  }

export default Faq
```

Here is the index.js

```
import Layout from '../components/layouts/layout'
import Faq from './faq'

import React, {Component} from 'react'

export default class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <Layout>
                <h1>I am Home Page</h1>
                <Faq />           
            </Layout>

        )
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to load faq.js into index.js?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61111933/unable-to-pass-props-in-next/61112443). While the answer provided refers to `getInitialProps`, the same holds true for `getStaticProps` (can only be [exported from a page and not a child component within page](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#only-allowed-in-a-page)), although you may or may be able to create a wrapper component.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `index.js` you've import `./faq` with name `About` but inside the render function you used it as `<Faq />`. Should be in this way:

```js
import Layout from '../components/layouts/layout'
import Faq from './faq'

import React, {Component} from 'react'

export default class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <Layout>
                <h1>I am Home Page</h1>
                <Faq />           
            </Layout>

        )
    }
}
```